# how to bind raw socket to specific interface

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, raw-sockets

My application is running on CentOS 5.5.
I'm using raw socket to send data:

```
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
if (sd < 0) {
  // Error
}
const int opt_on = 1;
rc = setsockopt(m_SocketDescriptor, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &opt_on, sizeof(opt_on));
if (rc < 0) {
  close(sd);
  // Error
}
struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = my_ip_address;

if (sendto(m_SocketDescriptor, DataBuffer, (size_t)TotalSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)  {
  close(sd);
  // Error
}
```

How can I bind this socket to specific network interface (say eth1)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Your program will lose portability unless you are sure your machines will have interfaces named the predefined names.

Comment: It is for embedded device, the portability is not needed.
I have 6 Ethernet ports and I need to send data using specific interface

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
const char *opt;
opt = "eth0";
const len = strnlen(opt, IFNAMSIZ);
if (len == IFNAMSIZ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Too long iface name");
    return 1;
}
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, opt, len);
```

First line: set up your variable

Second line: tell the program which interface to bind to

Lines 3-5: get length of interface name and check if it's size not too big.

Six line: set the socket options for socket `sd`, binding to the device `opt`.

setsockopt prototype:

```
int setsockopt(int s, int level, int optname, const void *optval, socklen_t optlen);
```

Also, make sure you include the `if.h`, `socket.h` and `string.h` header files

Comment: Thanks, it working, but with one small modification:

  ifreq Interface;

  memset(&Interface, 0, sizeof(Interface));

  strncpy(Interface.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, "eth1", IFNAMSIZ);

  if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &Interface, sizeof(Interface)) < 0) {

    close(sd);

    // Error

  }

Comment: SO_BINDTODEVICE only works if you run as root, right? (on Linux at least)

Comment: Strange it seems to be requiring ifreq structure, when socket(7) that the passed option is variable-length Zstring...

Comment: The first element of "struct ifreq" is the char[] name of the interface. You also still specify IFNAMSIZ. So this should be identical (just as appending any random buffer to "eth0" should work)

Comment: According to [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921602/919747), and my experience on CentOS 7, this does not work for a raw socket. Instead, you need to use `bind()`, not the `setsockopt()` approach shown here.

Comment: @JasonR: Your comment just cut short hours of frustration for myself and my coworker. (We are finally revving from CentOS 6 to 7 and have been banging our heads over why some legacy code isn't working.) Thank you!

Comment: Hi, does Windows OS has SO_BINDTODEVICE??

Answer (score 22):

As mentioned earlier, the correct thing to do is use the `struct ifreq` to specify the interface name. Here is my code sample.

```
#define SERVERPORT 5555
...
struct ifreq ifr;


/* Create the socket */
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sd < 0) 
{
    printf("Error in socket() creation - %s", strerror(errno));
}

/* Bind to eth1 interface only - this is a private VLAN */
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "eth1");
if ((rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr))) < 0)
{
    perror("Server-setsockopt() error for SO_BINDTODEVICE");
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    close(sd);
    exit(-1);
}

/* bind to an address */
memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("9.1.2.3");

int rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
```

I would also like to add that from a security perspective, while it is good to bind the socket to an interface, it does not make sense to use `INADDR_ANY` as the listening IP address. Doing so would make the port appear open in netstat on all network interfaces.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address    State     User Inode      PID/Program name
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:5555     0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    0    210898     26996/myserver
```

Instead, I specified an IP address specific to the interface being used (a private VLAN). This fixed the netstat output too:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address    State     User Inode      PID/Program name
tcp   0      0      9.1.2.3:5555     0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    0    210898     26996/myserver
```

Comment: Where is it specified that you use `struct ifreq` ?  My man page says "the
passed option is a variable-length null-terminated interface name string"

Comment: The problem you suggest (INADDR_ANY for SOCK_STREAM sockets) doesn't occur for the original poster, who was using SOCK_RAW.

Comment: @Bryan Both methods should work, at the very least on Linux. According to netdevice(7), the `ifr_name` string is the first member of `struct ifreq`, and therefore a pointer to `struct ifreq` or `char` work the same.

Comment: This is really the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Bind socket to specific interface IP address**

```
int bind_using_iface_ip(int fd, char *ipaddr, uint16_t port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in localaddr = {0};
    localaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET;
    localaddr.sin_port  = htons(port);
    localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);
    return bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &localaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
}
```

**Bind socket to specific interface name**

```
int bind_using_iface_name(int fd, char *iface_name)
{
    return setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface_name, strlen(iface_name))
}
```

In `bind_using_iface_ip`, to bind to any port `0` should be passed. And also if the `fd` is raw socket then need to pass port as `0`. This bind mechanism is common for all kind of sockets like raw, dgram and stream.

Comment: This is correct answer. We should be binding to the ip address. Not to an Interface?

Comment: but different interfaces may have same IP