# Error in binding socket to network interface

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to bind a socket to a interface in my application in Linux.I found some code stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998569/how-to-bind-raw-socket-to-specific-interface) but when I tried using this I was getting -1 as return value from **setsockopt**

Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "newfile.h"


int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{

scktfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 
char *opt;
opt = "eth0";

struct ifreq Interface; 
memset(&Interface, 0, sizeof(Interface));
strncpy(Interface.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ); 

int rtrn;
rtrn = setsockopt(scktfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,&Interface, sizeof(Interface));

  return 0;
}
```

I tried by modifying the code by looking at other examples but it didn't work. What might be the problem.

Comment: "I was getting -1 as return value from setsockopt" Okay. But what was the error number?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams how can i check the error number

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i am getting operation not permitted error

Comment: My first guess is you'd need to be running as root.  If you are, I don't know.

Comment: When you get -1 from any system call, call `perror()` immediately.

Comment: @TripeHound I am currently logged in as root user

Comment: Note: you define opt="eth0" but never use it :)

Comment: @hexasoft I am using strncpy(Interface.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ); earlier i tried by directly passing "eth0" to setsockopt at the place of &Interface

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams error number is 1

Comment: Probably not the case but did you check your interface name? Some systems don't name them "ethX". No paint to check.

Comment: @hexasoft mine is eth0

Comment: Well I just copy/paste your code on my laptop (last ubuntu). Just adding `int scktfd;` declaration (lack in your code) and removing the include (newfile.h), and adding call to perror(). Compile fine. As a standard user I get: Operation not permitted (+ returns -1). Running as root I get: Success (+ returns 0). It really looks like a permission problem!

Comment: @hexasoft how can i run it like a root ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92485/discussion-between-hexasoft-and-paul-sen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in chat the problem was that the code was not run as `root`, as stated first by TripeHound.

Binding to network interfaces is not allowed to anyone (you can spy programs/users network data…), so using root or a user with correct access to device is needed.