# How to open a socket on specific interface in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, raw-sockets

I want to know how it is possible to open simply a socket on a specific interface (eth0, wlan0, ...) in Node JS.

It seems to [be possible in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998569/how-to-bind-raw-socket-to-specific-interface) and possible also with ping command with `ping -I eth0 google.com`.

But how to do that with Node JS ?
I have seen nothing in [net.Socket documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect).

I have found [some code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3625#issuecomment-153005680) that wrap dynamic library but there should be a easier way to do that. No ?
Something like `socket.connect({host :"google.com", port:80, interface:"eth0"});`

Answer (score 0):

[`net.Socket.connect(options[, connectListener])`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener) accepts `localAddress`  parameter which specifies what address the socket should connect from. Each your physical interface has exactly one IP address attached to it*. So the proper way would be to determine an IP address of the interface you'd like to use and use the IP in `connect` call.

```
socket.connect({
    host: "google.com",
    port: 80,
    localAddress: somehowGetIPv4AddrOfInterface("eth0"),
 });
```

The OS will then determine the interface (eth0 in this case). A bit cumbersome, but it is a usual pattern to avoid dealing with lower level addresses when a higher level is available.

* - a little bit more if IPv6 is also configured, but this is rarely a problem.

Comment: hello. thanks for your answer. can you say more things about ipv6?

Comment: @kodmanyagha sorry, but I don't remember the details. I probably meant specifying `family` option (see the docs), or making sure some sort of local IPv6 is assigned to the interface (e. g. `ifconfig`).