# How to bypass the VPN for specific connections in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, openvpn

My (Windows) computer is connected with OpenVPN to my VPN provider. That means that *everything* goes through it, alternatively using its proxies as well for a little bit of variation.

In many situations, I don't want it to go through the VPN (or any proxy) when making a request. For example, when I use PHP to log in to my bank. Or when all proxies/VPNs are blocked from downloading a file, or loading a webpage, etc., which happens frequently. But then I'm stuck, because to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to tell PHP to "bypass the VPN and use my home IP address directly".

I would like something like:

```
php_bypass_VPN();
/* make cURL requests here */
php_restore_VPN();
```

Is it possible at all? If not, why is this not a major problem for anyone else? Or is it? It has caused *countless* issues for me, and not just in PHP context. For example, I would want the buffering local Internet radio station to go through my normal IP address as well, but no software I've ever seen provides any means to "bypass VPN".

If the solution involves hacking the OS and/or installing a bunch of spyware, I'll not be happy. Please tell me there is some simple way to do this, such as:

```
shell_exec('somebinary bypassvpntemporarily');
```

That would be swell, although a cross-platform solution would be vastly preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Most VPNs work in a way that they install a new network interface driver on your PC and make sure all traffic goes through it so it can encrypt it on the way out.
I guess you could try to go through a specific interface but I'm not sure that will overcome the VPN (heres how to get a specific interface [how to bind raw socket to specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998569/how-to-bind-raw-socket-to-specific-interface)).
Other than that you could create your own driver...